# Extra column when scanning JSON into CSV using .map, sorted order is lost

Tags: ruby, json, csv

I am writing a script to convert JSON data to an ordered CSV spreadsheet.

The JSON data itself does not necessarily contain all keys (some fields in the spreadsheet should say "NA").

Typical JSON data looks like this:

```
json = {"ReferringUrl":"N","PubEndDate":"2010/05/30","ItmId":"347628959","ParentItemId":"46999"}
```

I have a list of the keys found in each column of the spreadsheet:

```
keys = ["ReferringUrl", "PubEndDate", "ItmId", "ParentItemId", "OtherKey", "Etc"]
```

My thought was that I could iterate through each line of JSON like this:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(json)
result = (0..keys.length).map{ |i| parsed[keys[i]] || 'NA'} #add values associated with keys to an array, using NA if no value is present
CSV.open('file.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
    csv << keys #create headings on spreadsheet
    csv << result #load data associated with headings into the next line
end
```

Ideally, this would create a CSV file with the proper information in the proper order in a spreadsheet. However, what happens is the `result` data comes in completely out of order, and contains an extra column that I don't know what to do with.

Looking at the actual data, since there are actually about 100 keys and most of the fields contain NA, it is very difficult to determine what is happening.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra column comes from `0..keys.length` which includes the end of the range. The last value of `result` is going to be `parsed[keys[keys.length]]` i.e. `parsed[nil]` i.e. `nil`. You can avoid that entirely by mapping `keys` directly

```
result = keys.map { |key| parsed.fetch(key, 'NA') }
```

As for the random order of the values, I suspect you aren't giving us all of the relevant information, because I tested your code and the result came out in the same order as `keys`.

Comment: You were right, the order should be correct. I was using the wrong array for `keys`. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

[Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html) has two possible notations

```
..
```

and

```
...
```

`...` is exclusive, meaning the range (A...B)  would be not include B.

Change to

```
result = (0...keys.length).map{ |i| parsed[keys[i]] || 'NA'} #add values associated with keys to an array, using NA if no value is present
```

And see if that prevents the last value in that range from evaluating to `nil`.